# Generar numeros aleatorios Java

Tags: java, random

Necesito generar dos números aleatorios diferentes y luego multiplicarlos

```
partA =  (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;;
partB =  (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;;
correctAnswer = partA * partB;
wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer - 1;
wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer + 1;
```

Pero `partA` y `partB` me genera el mismo numero y en correctAnswer me entrega un resultado erroneo.

Comment: Podrias probar usando la clase Random.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque math.random() no genera números aleatorios si no pseudo aleatorios [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random) tenes información mas detallada, no es muy claro que es la variable n por la cual se multiplica, correctanswer y wronganswer1/2 tampoco se de que tipo son y no estoy seguro de a que te referís por erróneo, pero si corregís eso ya el problema del mismo numero debería dejar de existir

podes usar una library que sea algo mas cercano a un numero aleatorio o con distintas seeds, eso te va a asegurar 2 números distintos como dice el link!